# Using Jssor with Django Media files

Tags: django-templates, jssor

I am using django and jssor.

When i use jssor slideshow transition, image will disappear then show up if i use images in 'media' folder. If i use images in 'static' folder there won be.

Could someone tell me why ?

Django Model:

```
class Banner(models.Model):
    image = models.FileField(upload_to='Banner/%Y_%m_%d')
    link = models.TextField()
```

Django template:

```
...
    <div ...>
        {% for banner in banners %}
            <div>
                <a href={% url banner.link %}>
                    <img src="{{ banner.image.url }}">
                </a>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
...
```

JS:

```
var _SlideshowTransitions = [{...some setting ...}]

$SlideshowOptions: {
                $Class: $JssorSlideshowRunner$,
                $Transitions: _SlideshowTransitions,
                $TransitionsOrder: 1,
                $ShowLink: true
            },
```

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a problem of chrome. Every time when a new image element created in the document dynamically, it will load the image again event the image is already loaded in the same page. If your resource is not cache enabled for client side, it is high performance consuming.

To enable cache for client side, it is an option of your server, or controlled by program.

So, browser caches resources come from 'static' folder and not for resources come from 'media' folder.